# Passing a null AttributeValue into DynamoDb using AWS low level API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm attempting to update an item within a DynamoDB table using the C# low-level API as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemCRUD.html#UpdateItemLowLevelDotNet)

Here is my attempt at achieving this:

```
var response = DynamoClientProvider.Current.UpdateItem(new UpdateItemRequest
{
    TableName = "MyTable",
    Key = {{"TableId", new AttributeValue {S = "12345"}}},
    ExpressionAttributeNames =
    {
        {"#T","Timestamp"},
        {"#D","Data"}
        {"#K","MyKey"}
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues =
    {
        {":Timestamp", new AttributeValue("2016-2-3 00:00:00.000")},
        {":Data", new AttributeValue("some data")}
        {":MyKey", new AttributeValue("some other data")}
    },
    UpdateExpression = "SET #D = :Data, #T = :Timestamp, #K = :MyKey",
    ConditionExpression = "attribute_not_exists (Data)",
    ReturnValues = ReturnValue.ALL_OLD
});
```

This code works just fine, however there is an issue when `MyKey` is an empty string.  When this is empty, I get the following error:

> Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException: ExpressionAttributeValues
>   contains invalid value: Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain
>   exactly one of the supported datatypes for key :MyKey

I have therefore attempted to therefore pass in a null `AttributeValue` in order to delete the attribute in this case by setting it to the following:

```
new AttributeValue{NULL = true}
```

However this instead will set the value to be the string literal of `True`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure DynamoDB's types are nullable.

If you need to delete the attribute use 'SET #D = :Data, #T = :Timestamp REMOVE #K'

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense given that it's a low-level API